# Endomorphism of representations as tensors

Tags: representation-theory, topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces

I'm trying to solve the following exercise: prove that if $(\rho,V)$ is a unitary representation, then there's a linear isomorphism $\operatorname{End}_\mathbb{C}(\rho)\cong\rho^\ast\otimes\rho$ that induces an isomorphism of $G\times G$ representations.

I guess (it was not defined in the notes I'm reading) that $\operatorname{End}_\mathbb{C}(\rho)$ is the set of endomorphisms $V\to V$.

If the representation is finite-dimensional, the exercise if pretty easy (it basically follows from that fact that $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)\cong V^\ast\otimes W$). But if I had to guess, I would've guessed it does not hold in the infinite-dimensional case.

The exercise, though, seems to ask about general representations (the context is Peter-Weyl theorem).

So my question is: does the result hold for infinite-dimensional representations? If so, what's the proof idea?

Thanks!

Comment: The $\mathbb C$ in the subscript indicates that all linear maps from V to V are considered there. With your interpretation (maps that commute with the group) the result is very false (so, in particular, what you say is easy is impossible!)

Comment: "Wrong" and "easy" are not mutually exclusive :) Thanks! I corrected the question. So the notation $\operatorname{End}(\rho)$ denotes endomorphisms of the representation, but $\operatorname{End}_\mathbb{C}(\rho)$ denotes endomorphisms of the Hilbert space on which it operates?

Answer (score 1):

That isomorphism does not work for infinite dimensional V. In that case, the tensor product is isomorphic to the space of linear maps from V to V of finite rank.